# Updating Images in Response to Button Events

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uibutton

I have a view with several buttons and an ImageView. I would like to change the Image inside the ImageView every time a button is pressed, with a specific image associated with each button. I also have a default image that I assign when the view gets created.

However, when a button is pressed, in order for the user to see the image changes, I send `reloadInputViews` message to the main view. This causes for the default image to remain in the ImageView because because it gets set every time a view is loaded. I assign the default image in `viewDidLoad`, should I be assigning it elsewhere? Or is there another method for me to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your action method-(IBAction) for each button, change the image property of your imageView:

```
self.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed"yourImageName.png"];
```

No need to reload the whole view...

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because your UIImageView is probably not the first [responder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> **reloadInputViews**
>   Updates the custom input and accessory views when the object is the first responder.
>   - (void)reloadInputViews
>   **Discussion**
>   You can use this method to refresh the custom input view or input accessory view associated with the current object when it is the first responder. The views are replaced immediately—that is, without animating them into place. **If the current object is not the first responder, this method has no effect**.

Instead use a [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIView) method if you don't see the change.

> **setNeedsDisplay**
>   Marks the receiver’s entire bounds rectangle as needing to be redrawn.
>   - (void)setNeedsDisplay

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Should I be setting something as a first responder first?

Comment: @AndrewBarinow how were you setting your new image?

Comment: I had an array of `NSString` objects as a property of the View Controller and an `NSString` representing the current image. I set the image within the image view using that string and a particular index in the array.